# program "g++" and "gcc" not found in path

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, windows, gcc

I am using eclipse luna. I have installed CDT into it. For accessing GNU tool chain I have installed latest version of MinGW and given the path of MinGW\bin in environment variables.
But when I have built a test project(written in C), I am getting the following errors:

> Program "g++" not found in path
>   Program "gcc" not found in path

Info: I am using Windows 8 32 bit OS

Comment: It means that the path you specified in `PATH` variable is wrong.

Comment: have you tried compiling over cmd instead of eclipse?

Comment: You say you gave *the path of MinGW\bin in environment variables*. What environment variable ? The error from eclipse just says it did not find `gcc.exe` in PATH environment variable. What displays `echo %PATH%` in a cmd window ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had similar problem and I solved it by:

Installing g++ The GNU C++ compiler using Ubuntu Software Center

Changing in: Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings -> Discovery -> CDT GCC Build in Complier Settings [Shared]

from: ${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"

to: /usr/bin/${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"

I am using ubuntu but try the same in windows.

Be sure that you have installed g++ and then add whole path before $ as (path)${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"

I hope it helps.

Comment: OP's OS is Windows not Linux

Comment: I really doubt that OP can get g++ from Ubuntu Software Center and have it work under Windows ...

Comment: For sure no, i wrote him how i solve it, but perhaps he can solve it by adding path in front $

Answer (score 1):

Hi I just had a similar problem and i tried many of the solutions offered by the members and nothing worked. after a long time i managed to find the main issue it is the ANTI VIRUS! it blocks the gcc.exe and g++.exe 
Mke sure you disable every anti virus or make an exception.

(WINDOWS 7 64BIT Eclipse kepler)